# Laser_Ortho_Projector Transformation

Tags: ros, transforms, laser-scan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having tf issues with scan tool as in in this link -> http://wiki.ros.org/laser_ortho_projector

Under the package summary, it states that the tf transformation of world → base_ortho is already a provided transformation. Does this mean I still need to manually create a static transform between the world frame and base_ortho frame in my launch file? Because if I don't, rviz warns me that the base_ortho frame does not exist. So I am pretty confused what I actually need to do because at the moment the projected point cloud does not match the laser scans from my rplidar sensor.

I am hoping I will be able to obtain something like this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHsdwQbqc8Y

Currently when I do a top down view on RVIZ, the raw laser scans do not coincide with the point cloud representation.

Please help me out. My project is due really soon :(

Thanks in advance!

My launch file:

```
 <launch>
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
 <node pkg="laser_ortho_projector" type="laser_ortho_projector_node" name="laser_ortho_projector" 
    output="screen">
    <param name="use_imu" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" type="bool" value="true"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_map" 
    args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /world /map 100" />
  
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_base" 
    args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /base_link 100" /> 

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser" 
    args="0 0 0.5 3.14159 -0.57189 0 /base_link /laser 100" /> 
   
</launch>
```

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254497/laser_ortho_projector-transformation/) by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
Looking at the page you linked, I see:

> `~publish_tf` (`bool`, default: `false`)

> whether to publish the tf between the `fixed_frame` and the `base_ortho` frames as a tf.

Have you changed that value to `true`? Otherwise I would not expect `laser_ortho_projector` to publish the TF frame.

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-12**:
Yes, I changed the value to true from the start. I edited the demo.launch file provided. I have included the launch file above. Do I need to create a base_ortho frame before the laser_ortho_projector is able to generate the tf transformation?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:\

> Yes, I changed the value to true from the start.

Please always include *all* relevant information in your posting. We cannot guess what you have and have not already done.

Please include a screenshot of `rqt_tf_tree` after you've `roslaunch`ed your current launch file.

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-12**:
Sorry, I was referring to your question regarding setting the `publish_tf` to `true`. I have included the screenshot of the `rqt_tf_tree` above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I read the code, having `use_imu` set to `false` (and implicitly, leaving `use_pose` as `true` ([here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/9d88705676eac933569c2c08b667bfde6b06e574/laser_ortho_projector/src/laser_ortho_projector.cpp#L62-L65)), leads to the node subcribing to a `geometry_msgs/Pose` topic ([here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/9d88705676eac933569c2c08b667bfde6b06e574/laser_ortho_projector/src/laser_ortho_projector.cpp#L78-L82)).

Looking at where `publish_tf_` is checked, we find it in the `sensor_msgs/Imu` callback ([here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/9d88705676eac933569c2c08b667bfde6b06e574/laser_ortho_projector/src/laser_ortho_projector.cpp#L114)) and in the `geometry_msgs/Pose` callback ([here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/9d88705676eac933569c2c08b667bfde6b06e574/laser_ortho_projector/src/laser_ortho_projector.cpp#L135)).

Nowhere else is the `world → base_ortho` frame published.

I'm guessing you don't have a publisher that publishes `geometry_msgs/Pose` on a `pose` topic, and since you have `use_imu` set to `false`, I'm assuming you don't have an imu either.

That would explain why you don't see the frame: it's not published.

---

As to why that `pose` subscriber, and the corresponding `use_pose` parameter are not documented, I don't know. Would be nice if you could update the wiki page to include those.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-12**:
Oh I see. How do I go about publishing the `geometry_msgs/Pose` on a `pose` topic?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
I think the node is expecting a 6dof pose reference (relative to some global frame). Perhaps you could use some sensor fusion node for that.

But I just read the code. I have no experience with this particular node, so I could be wrong.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
If you have an imu that could also work (but you'd have to update your launch file parameters).

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-18**:
The problem is I don't have an imu so im depending solely on `geometry_msgs/pose`. Is there a way to publish a pose since I am planning to fix my sensor at a 30deg angle. I thought the code automatically changes the static transform into a `pose_msg`? ([here](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/indigo/laser_ortho_projector/src/laser_ortho_projector.cpp#L129))

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-18**:
I did some debugging and realized the execution of the code totally skipped the `Pose` callback and went straight to `scan` callback, where it just ran continuously in a loop. Is there a way to make it go through the `pose` callback?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-19**:\

> Is there a way to make it go through the `pose` callback?

Yes. By publishing a `Pose` to the `pose` topic.

Tha's what I wrote earlier: apparently the node works either with IMU msgs *or* a `geometry_msgs/Pose` published by some other node.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-19**:\

> went straight to `scan` callback, where it just ran continuously in a loop

not continuously: it'll iterate over all ranges in the current scan.

**Comment by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on 2017-02-19**:
I have a turtlebot with a kobuki base. Do you think there are any turtlebot nodes that can help me publish the `pose` msg? Sorry I am still in the process of learning ROS, thank you so much for your patience.